# React Little State Machine clear data

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

state-machine with react-hook-form to make my forms, but after submit the form i want to clear the storage after submit;

This is how i create my store;

```
createStore({
  data: {}
});
```

And this is my Submit function

```
const onSubmit = (data:any) => {
        action(data);
        props.onSubmit(state.data);
        // I need a function to clear the data to not complete my forms after i submit
      }
```

Here a little example that i want:
https://codesandbox.io/s/delete-data-little-state-machine-q3w0g
In "step3"i want to clear the data after click on button

Comment: More code would help.  Could you create a codesandbox?

Comment: Yes i'll create one, just some few minutes

Comment: @jack.benson here my example https://codesandbox.io/s/delete-data-little-state-machine-q3w0g  in step 3 i want clear the data :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to create another action and pass that to the hook.  You can see examples of this [in the docs](https://github.com/bluebill1049/little-state-machine#-usestatemachine).  Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/delete-data-little-state-machine-forked-jj57o?file=/src/Step3.js):

clearAction.js

```
export default function clearAction(state, payload) {
  return {
    data: {}
  };
}
```

Step3.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStateMachine } from "little-state-machine";
import clearAction from "./clearAction";

const Step3 = (props) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const { state, action } = useStateMachine(clearAction);
  const onSubit = (data) => {
    action(data);
    props.history.push("./resultFinal");
    console.log(state, action);
    action();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubit)}>
      <h2>Clear Data</h2>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Step3);
```

Note in the examples provided in the docs you can pass multiple actions to the hook as needed.

Comment: Thanks @jack.benson, but i have one question, can i make " useStateMachine(clearAction,UpdateAction);" and choose which function will be called when i call "action( )"?

Comment: const { actions } = useStateMachine({ clearAction,UpdateAction } );

then you can do actions.clearAction