# clear store in little-state-machine

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, session-storage

I am using `little-state-machine` (https://github.com/bluebill1049/little-state-machine) with `react-router` for a wizard on a client's site and I need to reset the store when a user returns to the wizard landing page. I followed this answer in stack overflow ([React Little State Machine clear data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64822032/react-little-state-machine-clear-data)) but I can’t get it to work.  I can’t show the full application, but from the below can you see anything wrong with what I have done.

**App.js**

```
createStore({
  data
});

function App() {
  
    return (
      <StateMachineProvider>
        <DevTool />
        <div className="container">
          ...
          <Router>
            <Steps />
          </Router>
        </div>
      </StateMachineProvider>
    );
  }

  export default App;
```

**Steps.js**

```
....
import { useStateMachine } from "little-state-machine";
import clearAction from "./lsm/actions/clearAction";
...

export default () => {
    ....
   const location = useLocation();
   const { state, actions } = useStateMachine({ clearAction });
   ...
   
   useEffect(() => {
   
       let step = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
       // landing page location = http://site.co.uk/wizard
       // steps have url = http://site.co.uk/wizard/step[1-4]
       if(!step){
     
           actions.clearAction();
   
       }

   }, []);

return (...);
};
```

**clearAction.js**

```
export default function clearAction(state, payload) {
   return {};
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see of the code snippet you've shared you are it appears as though this `Steps` component is possibly rendering a `Route` or set of `Route`s corresponding to the wizard steps. If I understand your question/issue you want to reset the wizard any time the the step is `0` or some falsey value.

The issue is that `Steps` only runs this check once when it mounts. To resolve you can add the `location` object as a dependency to the `useEffect` hook so the hook's callback is triggered any time the `location` changes. The `step` condition will check if on the wizard landing page and reset the state machine.

```
export default () => {
  ....
  const location = useLocation();
  const { state, actions } = useStateMachine({ clearAction });
  ...
   
  useEffect(() => { 
    let step = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
    // landing page location = http://site.co.uk/wizard
    // steps have url = http://site.co.uk/wizard/step[1-4]
    if (!step) {
      actions.clearAction();
    }
  }, [location]); // <-- add location as a dependency

  return (...);
};
```